# Applescript to repeat complete script for files in a folder

Tags: applescript, repeat

I have managed to get all this code together now and just need the last step to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have setup this script to open an .xlsx file in a folder, change the date, save it then PDF to another folder. It then creates a mail by looking up the client code (found in the excel file) to subsequently look for this code in a Database.xlsx file and return the e-mail address of the client and add it to the "To" field in mail. It then attaches the newly created PDF to this mail and I can just click and send.

The script stops after the first .xlsx file has been opened, just so I can check the details is correct before it PDF's and creates the mail.

My question is: How do I get this process to repeat for each file in the initial folder? I have tried the repeat function, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
--Complete script for updating invoice, saving (as PDF too in seperate folder) and e-mailing invoices

--Select the first file in a folder and then repeat for the next

set theFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Choose Folder containing .xlsx invoices")
set theFolderList to list folder theFolder without invisibles

repeat with x from 1 to count of theFolderList
    set theFile to theFolder & item x of theFolderList
    set theNewFile to theFolder & theFile
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open theFile
        set ActiveClientCode to value of range ("B1")
    end tell


--Change date of one cell to date of next month

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open "/Users/pienaar0/Documents/AdminAssist/" & ActiveClientCode & ".xlsx"
    set d to value of cell ("A1")
    set d to my MonthAdd(d)
    set value of cell ("A1") to d
end tell

on MonthAdd(d)
    set m to ((month of d as integer) + 1)
    set ddd to day of d
    if m > 12 then
        set m to m - 12
        set year of d to (year of d) + 1
    end if
    if {m} is in {4, 6, 9, 11} and ddd = 31 then --AppleScript treats "Apr 31" as May 1,
        set day of d to 30
    end if
    set month of d to m
    if m = 2 and month of d as integer = 3 then --AppleScript treats "Feb 31" as Mar 3,
        set day of d to 1 -- Mar 1
        set d to d - (1 * days) -- last day of Feb
    end if
    return d
end MonthAdd

property dialog_timeout : 36000
display dialog "Make sure the invoice is correct before clicking OK" buttons {"OK"} giving up after dialog_timeout
set the user_choice to the button returned of the result


--Save document and PDF
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    save active workbook
    save active workbook in "Macintosh HD:Users:pienaar0:Documents:AdminAssistPDF:" & ActiveClientCode & ".pdf" as PDF file format


end tell

--Find e-mail address, and Name in Database (Check filepath and ranges)

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open "Users/pienaar0/Documents/Database.xlsx"
    set searchRange to range ("D2:D5")
    set foundRange to find searchRange what ActiveClientCode with match case
    set fRow to first row index of foundRange
    set ClientEmail to value of range ("C" & fRow as text)
    set ClientFirstname to value of range ("A" & fRow as text)
    (* do something with the foundRange *)
end tell

--Create e-mail

tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Your monthly invoice", content:"Dear " & ClientFirstname & ",

I trust this mail finds you well?

Please find attached your monthly invoice for your immediate consideration.

Regards,

AdminAssist

"}
    set message signature of theMessage to signature "Replies & Forwards"
    delay 1
    tell content of theMessage
        make new attachment with properties {file name:"/Users/pienaar0/Documents/AdminAssist/PDF/" & ActiveClientCode & " Sheet1.pdf"}
        tell theMessage
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:ClientEmail}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your handler outside of the repeat block:

```
property dialog_timeout : 36000
--Complete script for updating invoice, saving (as PDF too in seperate folder) and e-mailing invoices
--Select the first file in a folder and then repeat for the next

set theFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Choose Folder containing .xlsx invoices")
tell application "System Events" to set theFolderList to name of every file of folder theFolder whose visible is true

repeat with x from 1 to count of theFolderList
    set theFile to theFolder & item x of theFolderList
    set theNewFile to theFolder & theFile
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open theFile
        set ActiveClientCode to value of range ("B1")
    end tell

    --Change date of one cell to date of next month
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open "/Users/pienaar0/Documents/AdminAssist/" & ActiveClientCode & ".xlsx"
        set d to value of cell ("A1")
        set d to my MonthAdd(d)
        set value of cell ("A1") to d
    end tell

    display dialog "Make sure the invoice is correct before clicking OK" buttons {"OK"} giving up after dialog_timeout
    set the user_choice to the button returned of the result

    --Save document and PDF
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        save active workbook
        save active workbook in "Macintosh HD:Users:pienaar0:Documents:AdminAssistPDF:" & ActiveClientCode & ".pdf" as PDF file format
    end tell

    --Find e-mail address, and Name in Database (Check filepath and ranges)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        open "Users/pienaar0/Documents/Database.xlsx"
        set searchRange to range ("D2:D5")
        set foundRange to find searchRange what ActiveClientCode with match case
        set fRow to first row index of foundRange
        set ClientEmail to value of range ("C" & fRow as text)
        set ClientFirstname to value of range ("A" & fRow as text)
        (* do something with the foundRange *)
    end tell

    --Create e-mail

    tell application "Mail"
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Your monthly invoice", content:"Dear " & ClientFirstname & ",

I trust this mail finds you well?

Please find attached your monthly invoice for your immediate consideration.

Regards,

AdminAssist

"}
        set message signature of theMessage to signature "Replies & Forwards"
        delay 1
        tell content of theMessage
            make new attachment with properties {file name:"/Users/pienaar0/Documents/AdminAssist/PDF/" & ActiveClientCode & " Sheet1.pdf"}
            tell theMessage
                make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:ClientEmail}
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat


on MonthAdd(d)
    set m to ((month of d as integer) + 1)
    set ddd to day of d
    if m > 12 then
        set m to m - 12
        set year of d to (year of d) + 1
    end if
    if {m} is in {4, 6, 9, 11} and ddd = 31 then --AppleScript treats "Apr 31" as May 1,
        set day of d to 30
    end if
    set month of d to m
    if m = 2 and month of d as integer = 3 then --AppleScript treats "Feb 31" as Mar 3,
        set day of d to 1 -- Mar 1
        set d to d - (1 * days) -- last day of Feb
    end if
    return d
end MonthAdd
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you! I will try this, but that is surely the anwswer. Thank you so much!